# Why do I get a conversion error when calling this from outside my class?

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

I have a class I'm trying to write some unit tests for but I've getting conversion errors:

```
1>c:\projects\myproj\unittests\UnitTest_MyClass.h(60): error C2664: 'MyClass::MyFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'GenericCollections::CircularBuffer<T> ^' to 'GenericCollections::CircularBuffer<T> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=const MyProj::DataPacket ^
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=MyProj::DataPacket ^const 
1>          ]
```

Class under test (just a snippet):

```
public ref class MyClass
{
protected:
    double MyFunc(GenericCollections::CircularBuffer<const MyProj::DataPacket^>^ data, int &firstIndex, int &lastIndex);
```

Unit test (just a snippet):

```
[Test]
public ref class UnitTest_MyClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    [Test]
    void Test_0001_MyFunc()
    {
        GenericCollections::CircularBuffer<const MyProj::DataPacket^>^ data = nullptr; // This will eventually be populated with test data
        int firstIndex = 0;
        int lastIndex = data->Length-1;

        double funcResult = MyFunc(data, firstIndex, lastIndex); // causes error C2664
    }
```

I can call this method in the same way from within the class under test and it works fine so why does it fail when I'm calling it from the unit tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an important detail missing from the question, but can be inferred.  This failed to compile because you are importing the type definitions through an assembly reference instead of an #include.  The expected way you'd unit-test this code.

You have to keep in mind that the `const` keyword is a problem, the CLR completely misses the notion.  It is only ever meaningful if it is enforced, that will not happen when your code is used by another managed language, like VB.NET or C#.  Languages that don't have anything resembling `const` the way it is used in native C++.

Metadata in the CLR does allow a language to add an arbitrary attribute to variables and parameter types through the [modopt] construct.  The C++/CLI compiler uses this when it emits the metadata for Func<>, something you can see with ildasm.exe:

```
   MyFunc(class GenericCollections.CircularBuffer`1<
          class DataPacket modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst)
       > data,
       // etc...
```

Edited to fit, note the emitted [modopt] on the type parameter.  That is however not enough to completely express the various ways in which *const* can be applied in native C++.  The *data* argument could be `const T^ data`, `T^ data const` or `const T^ data const`.  Not something that can be expressed with just that single [modopt].

You could argue that this is a compiler defect, but it really is not, this restriction was intentional.  They did make the compiler smart enough to note that `const` is ambiguous here and generate an appropriate error message.

Well, not that much you can do about this.  It will not be a problem when you #include the type definitions, the compiler then knows enough about the declaration.  Maybe you can rejigger your project, albeit that it isn't exactly very practical.  My usual advice with this problem is to just give up on the notion that `const` is useful in managed code.  It is not, C++/CLI is an interop language and the usual consumer of this kind of code doesn't know beans about const and therefore won't enforce it.

Comment: We took your advice and gave up on `const` - thanks as always for the help Hans :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with
[
    T=const Anchor::DataPacket ^
]
and
[
    T=Anchor::DataPacket ^const 
]
```

It looks like the compiler is getting mixed up between a reference to a const object and a const reference to an object. The error description page for [C2664](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd(v=vs.90).aspx) doesn't show what happens explicitly when passing a collection of const references. I think I would try removing the const from the template.

Comment: Removing the `const` does indeed stop that compiler error but does mean my collection can accidentally be modified now which is why I'd added that const in there in the first place.